# Remove entries that occur less than x times

Tags: r

I have a data frame :

```
dat <- data.frame(
  userId = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "3"),
  rating = c(4.5,3,3.5,4,5)
)
```

Each userId has many ratings. I want to remove any userId that does not occur more than x times. I have no idea how I could do this, could anyone please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [dplyr](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) package:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(userId) %>%
  filter(n() > 2)
```

Which gets you:

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
Groups: userId [1]

  userId rating
  (fctr)  (dbl)
1      1    4.5
2      1    3.0
3      1    3.5
```

Comment: Sorry, I have included an example of my data in the OP now.

Comment: Thanks for adding that.  I reformatted my answer to match your sample data - though the code still works so remains the same.